# Select a date without time (SQL Server (+)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

I would like to retrieve a date minus 1 year, but without time notation.

The following query

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Output:

```
2015-03-30 10:48:04.220
```

What I want is `2015-03-30 00:00:00:000`

Similar to:

```
(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Which results in: `2016-03-30 00:00:00.000`

What is the correct or easiest way to do this?

Comment: why don't use CAST( field AS DATE) ?

Comment: "What I want is `2015-03-30 00:00:00:000`". Strange, but it looks like that includes a fairly precise representation of midnight. Do you want the time-of-day or just a [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2008 and higher, you should convert to date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, (DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())))
```

On older versions, you can do the following:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())))
```